# How to remove parameter from a URL in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, url

How can I remove the parameters from a URL after processing in my controller? Like this one:

```
mydomain/mypage?filter%5Bstatus_id%5D
```

to

```
mydomain/mypage
```

I want to remove the parameters after the `?` then I want to use the new URL in my view file. Is this possible in laravel 5.2? I have been trying to use other approaches but unfortunately they are not working well as expected. I also want to include my data in my view file. The existing functionality is like this:

```
   public function processData(IndexRequest $request){
      //process data and other checkings

      return view('admin.index')
            ->with([
                'data'   => $data,
                'person' => $persons,
            ]);
   }
```

I want it to be like:

```
    public function processData(IndexRequest $request){
      //process data and other checkings

      // when checking the full url is 
      // mydomain/mypage?filter%5Bstatus_id%5D
      // then I want to remove the parameters after the question mark which can be done by doing
      // request()->url()
      // And now I want to change the currently used url using the request()->url() data
      return view('admin.index')
            ->with([
                'data'   => $data,
                'person' => $persons,
            ]);
   }
```

I'm stuck here for days already. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Your `public function` doesn't have a name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request()->url()`, it will return the URL without the parameters

Comment: Yes I have used that, but I want it to be redirected to that url with the data I want. I will update my question for further details.

Comment: Updated. I hope you can help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function processData(IndexRequest $request){
  $url_with_parameters = $request()->url();
   $url= explode("?", $url_with_parameters );

   //avoid redirect loop
   if (isset($url[1])){
   return URL::to($url[0]);
   }
   else{
   return view('admin.index')
            ->with(['data' => $data,
           'person' =>$persons,]);
}
}
```

add new url to your routes and assuming it will point to SomeController@SomeMethod, the SomeMethod should be something like :

```
public function SomeMethod(){
    // get $data and $persons

    return view('admin.index')
            ->with(['data' => $data,
           'person' =>$persons,]);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes this is right but how can I use this as my new url with the data?

Comment: you want to redirect to the new url?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the url without the parameter with the same needed data in my view file as stated above.

Comment: Your description isn't really clear, do you want to send new url to be shown in 'admin.index' view ( in a link or something ) or you want the page you are returning to have that url in the address bar of browser?

Comment: I want the page that I am returning to have that URL in my address bar.

Comment: You are going to end up with a redirect loop 

Comment: To be honest @SibaAl you are not going to fix it since it looks like this is what the OP is asking for 

Comment: @ChristopheHubert to be honest.. I don't understand the logic behind this question..you want non-url-showing data..use post! :)

Comment: Well, let's see what the OP has to say and we will try our best to help

Comment: @SibaAl Thank you so much for your efforts, I also tried post method but some data in my view file (the page that calls this function) has array on their filter data, that is why I can't perfectly assign it in the input fields.